# Reset circuit (momentary button toggle as ON/OFF using 555 timer circuit) from an external signal

Tags: 555

I have this "MOMENTARY BUTTON TOGGLE AS ON/OFF USING 555 TIMER CIRCUIT". I want to turn on/turn off the circuit using single momentary button and also being able to turn off the circuit from one of the NodeMCU GPIO pin.

As of now, I can only toggle ON/OFF using the momentary button.
The problem is I didn't know how can I reset the circuit when a GPIO pin from NodeMCU has changed state.

I badly needed help. Thank you very much in advanced. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the output low with a GPIO by using a transistor to drive the /RESET input low.

Eg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzMH2t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>